# yii2 Multiple model and select2 non-unique id problem

Tags: dom, yii2, jquery-select2

Hi all i'm a noob and i'm tryng to use a multiple model with a select2 in my model i call two time the same table because i write in it two time.
i use a table called "Luoghi" where i write the birthplace and where you live, so i need to use it twice

```
 public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $ClientiLuoghis = ClientiLuoghi::find()->where(['IDCliente'=>$id])->one();
    if (!$ClientiLuoghis) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The ClientiLuoghis was not found.");
    }
    $residenza= Luoghi::find()->where(['ID'=>$ClientiLuoghis->IDLuogo])->one();
    if (!$residenza) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The  residenza was not found.");
    }
    $lnascita=Luoghi::find()->where(['ID'=>$model->IDLuogoNascita])->one();
    if (!$lnascita) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The  lnascita was not found.");
    }
    $contatti=contatti::find()->where(['IDCliente'=>$id])->all();
 if (!$contatti) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The   contatti was not found.");
    }
    
    $model->Scenario = 'update';
    $residenza->Scenario = 'update';
    $lnascita->Scenario = 'update';
    $contatti->Scenario = 'update';
    if($contatti===null) {
   throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
   return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,'residenza'=>$residenza,'lnascita'=>$lnascita,'contatti'=>$contatti
    ]);}
```

the action works without problems, the trouble is in this

```
<h3><?= Html::encode('Luogo di Nascita') ?></h3>         
          <table width="90%">
             <tr> <td width="40%">  <?= $form->field($model, 'DataNascita')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'DataNascita'],
            'removeButton' => false,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            ]
                 ]); ?></TD><td width="5%"><td width="40%"></tr>
                                            <tr> <td width="40%">        <?=
                $form->field($lnascita, 'IDComune')->
                widget(Select2::classname(), ['data' => $listComnas,
                    'id' => 'IDcomune',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Seleziona Comune ...',  ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
        ])->label('Comune');
        ?></td><td width="5%"><td width="40%">
 <?=  $form->field($lnascita, 'IDProvincia')->
                widget(Select2::classname(), ['data' => $listPRnas,
                    'id' => 'IDProvincia',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Seleziona Provincia ...',  ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
        ])->label('Provincia');
        ?>
 
<h3><?= Html::encode('Luogo di Residenza') ?></h3>         
          <table width="90%">
                <tr> <td width="40%">        <?=
                $form->field($residenza, 'IDComune')->
                widget(Select2::classname(), ['data' => $listComres,
                    
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Seleziona Comune ...',  ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
        ])->label('Comune');
        ?></td><td width="5%"><td width="40%">
 <?=  $form->field($residenza, 'IDProvincia')->
                widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => $listPRres,
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Seleziona Provincia ...',  ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
        ])->label('Provincia');
        ?></td> </tr>
```

the second IDcomune and IDProvincia select2 are empty and blank  and i get this advise

**[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #luoghi-indirizzo input#luoghi-indirizzo.form-control input#luoghi-indirizzo.form-control**

Any ideas about how to solve?

Comment: your question is difficult to understand for me, do you want multiple models inside one selec2? , BTW try to red this [https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-multiple-models](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-multiple-models) maybe it gives you some ideas for your problem

Comment: Hi Sfili, no the problem is about the dom object , when yii load the the id of the two field   in the second select2  have the same id of the first, i'm asking if there is a way to avoid this or how to use an alias or similar